# Firefox all but freezes during large file upload; Ajax progress bar infeasible; IE6 works fine

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-6, progress-bar

I want to provide a progress bar for my users who upload very large files.  I did some reading and implemented what should be a pretty straightforward solution:

- I have a `<form>` element that contains an file input element; its `target` is set to the ID of a hidden iframe.
- On the server side, there's some Spring magic that attaches an object to the user's session; the progress of the upload can be queried from this object.
- After submitting the form, I start a repeating Ajax call using `setInterval` that queries the server for the percent-complete using the aforementioned session object.  The call repeats every half-second, skipping the Ajax call if the previous call has not yet completed.  I use the data from the call to update the `width` of an onscreen element.  When the server call reports that the upload is complete, I clear the interval timer.

I created a 100-megabyte file and uploaded it using my interface.  This is using Firefox 3.6.3.  What I found is that although the upload takes 20-25 seconds, the progress bar doesn't get updated until the very end.  Moreover, the entire browser is basically frozen until the upload completes.

I assumed that my method must be flawed, but I tried the same page using IE6, and was utterly amazed when it behaved as I had designed it to--the progress bar got updated every half second, and the whole upload only took about 15 seconds, much faster than Firefox.

I don't have many add-ons installed, but I tried disabling Firebug and restarting my browser.  This marginally improved the performance--I got perhaps a single additional progress bar update mid-upload--but still far from acceptable.

Can anyone tell me what I can do to bring Firefox's performance up to the level of IE6?  Ugh, I can't believe I actually typed that.

EDIT:

I just tried uploading a large file from a Firefox 3.6.3 browser on a different machine than the one that's running my web server, and it worked fine.  Huh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was a Linux thing rather than a Firefox thing.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem using Firefox from Windows 7 and Mac to a server running on the Mac and found Firebug to be the problem. On your remote machine, I suspect you were not running Firebug. Disable or uninstall firebug and it should work fine.